# Custom beamer blocks for pros and cons?

Tags: beamer, color

I want to be able to define custom block environments in Beamer.
That is, where for now I use `alertblock` and `exampleblock` I would rather use `problock` and `conblock` for a pro/con discussion.

This just seems more appropriate because a con is not an alert and a pro is not an example.

The code should then look something like this:

```
\begin{problock}{Pros}
\begin{itemize}
\item Good reason
\item Better reason
\end{itemize}
\end{problock}

\begin{conblock}{Contra}
\begin{itemize}
\item Small drawback
\item Big drawback
\end{itemize}
\end{conblock}
```

For each defined block environment I would then provide the proper formatting overrides in the preamble such as `bg`, `fg` and especially the structure color for bullets and such.

which would be the most *beamer-like* way to go?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a simple example (emulating the definition of `alertblock` as it appears in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`) of the definition of a new block-like environment; using `\setbeamercolor` and `\setbeamertemplate` you can then customize the different elements of the new block (background and foreground color for title and body, aspect of the items in an `itemize` environment, etc.). You can procceed analogously for the definition of the `conblock` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newenvironment<>{problock}[1]{%
  \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=orange!20!black}
       \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=olive!50}
       \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!20!black}
       \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
     }%
      \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{A regular alert block with regular itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First.
  \end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
\begin{problock}{A customized pro block with customized itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First.
  \end{itemize}
\end{problock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this worked like a charm. I am using a custom sty file though so I placed the `\newenvironment` there which also works.

Comment: probably you also would like to adjust `\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=orange!20!black}`