# Change color of itemize in beamer alertblock

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

How can I change the color of bullets in an `itemize` list within an `alertblock` in beamer?

I use

```
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{<color>}
```

to set the color of the bullets throughout the document. But I want a different color when the bullets are inside an `alertblock` environment. I've tried

```
\setbeamercolor{block itemize item alerted}{<color>}
```

and

```
\setbeamercolor{block alerted itemize item}{<color>}
```

but neither seems to do anything.

**Update:**
This is not the same question as [Custom beamer blocks for pros and cons?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/custom-beamer-blocks). I want to modify the alertblock environment. I don't want to create a new environment.

Comment: Does this question helps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/custom-beamer-blocks

Comment: I think it's almost the same question

Comment: `block itemize item alerted` or `block alerted itemize item` doesn't exist. [Here](http://science.thilucmic.fr/spip.php?article35) you can obtain a complete `templates` list. I think you will need to use @karathan link.

Comment: That question was about creating new block environments. I was hoping to simply modify the existing alertblock environment. Perhaps it is not possible.

Answer (score 15):

Just alter the parent structure:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%title
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=white,bg=brown}
%body
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=black!90,bg=brown!60!yellow}
% parent of all alerts default is red
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\begin{itemize}
\item item 
\end{itemize}
\begin{alertblock}{alert block}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 
\end{itemize}
\end{alertblock}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would not recommend to use exactly this color scheme but it shows how itemize items and the background can be adjusted individually. This will effect `enumerate` environments and any other alert as well.

Additional tipp: instead of guessing beamer templates which are not listed in the guide just look them up in the `beamer<color/inner/outer>themedefault.sty` files in the beamer tree.

Comment: It doesn't work if you have ever been set a beamercolor for itemize with `\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=\colortheme, bg=white}`. If I underdstand, default color of itemize is the structure color. How can I have itemize bullet with a different color than the structure and keep the fact that itemize color change inside a block ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify only the alerted block environment and/or you used something like `\setbeamercolor*{itemize}{fg=\colortheme, bg=white}` to use a custom color on most items you'll want to add a template only for alert blocks, like this:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=red}%
}{}
```

This will only change the color of itemize items **inside** alerted blocks.