# Beamer: how to make theorem-like block (with free title)

Tags: beamer, theorems, italic

I often use CambridgeUS, the only negative part about is that when I put theorems in blocks, it's not see clear where that theorem ends.
So I would like the body of the theorem to be in italic. 
However, I also want to be able to choose the title, so instead of "Theorem" I would want "Theorem (Erdos, 1960)".

What is the best way to do this?

Should I make a new type of block environment, or change the theorem environment?

I could of course use ordinary blocks and always make it italic by hand, but that looks like a nasty solution.

Comment: With `CambridgeUS` theme, `\begin{theorem}[Erdos, 1960] ... \end{theorem}` types theorem text in italics inside a shadowed block which perfectly shows where theorem ends. So, please, could you better explain what's the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code, to define your custom block:

```
\newenvironment<>{proposition}[1][\undefined]{%
\begin{actionenv}#2%
\ifx#1\undefined%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Proposition}%
\else%
   \def\insertblocktitle{Proposition ({\em#1})}%
\fi%
\par%
\mode<presentation>{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=yellow!50!black}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=yellow!20}
}%
\usebeamertemplate{block begin}\em}
{\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}
```

which has been adapted from here:
 [Custom beamer blocks for pros and cons?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/custom-beamer-blocks).
Note that an \if has been inserted to typeset either Proposition in the title, when no optional title is given, or Proposition (*Name of Proposition*) if such an optional name is provided.

The main text has been tweaked to be italic, by inserting the \em command after the \usebeamertemplate{block begin}.

Also, colors have been defined (which was my original motivation for implementing a custom definition in beamer, since using the package thmtools is problematic in beamer when a background color is specified).

In this way you can define definition, assumption, proposition, lemma, theorem, corollary, remark blocks, with possibly different colors each.
Use them as:

```
\begin{proposition}
   Main text, no custom name in the title.
\end{proposition}
```

when you just want the main text, or if you also want to specify a name in italics within parentheses, then use:

```
\begin{proposition}[optional name, will become italic]
   Main text
\end{proposition}
```

In case that one prefers the main body text to remain normal (and not in italics), then removing the \em command from after \usebeamertemplate{block begin} will suffice.