# Different colors for different types of blocks in beamer

Tags: beamer

In a beamer presentation, I’d like to set up different colors for normal blocks, definition blocks, theorem blocks, proof blocks, example blocks…

Ideally I’d set those up using `\usebeamercolor` commands. I can do it for example blocks, and for all other kinds of blocks at once, as illustrated in the sample below (compiled using XeLaTeX). But I can’t find how to do it for specific, non-example, types of blocks.

I suppose “[Custom beamer blocks for pros and cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/custom-beamer-blocks-for-pros-and-cons/)” points towards some solution, but I’d prefer (somehow) inheriting from the existing special block environment definitions rather than define new environments from scratch.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg}

\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=example text.fg,bg=example text.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!50!bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{My block}
        A block.
    \end{block}
    \begin{definition}[My definition]
        A definition.
    \end{definition}
    \begin{theorem}[My theorem]
        A theorem.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}[My proof]
        A proof.
    \end{proof}
    \begin{example}[My example]
        An example.
    \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg}

\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=example text,fg=example text.fg,bg=example text.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{parent=normal text,use=block title example,bg=block title example.bg!50!bg}

\addtobeamertemplate{proof begin}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=red, bg=red!30!white}
}{}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=orange!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=orange, bg=orange!30!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{
 \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
 \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=pink!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=pink, bg=pink!30!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
 \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
 \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{My block}
        A block.
    \end{block}

    \begin{definition}[My definition]
        A definition.
    \end{definition}

    \begin{theorem}[My theorem]
        A theorem.
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}[My proof]
        A proof.
    \end{proof}
    \begin{example}[My example]
        An example.
    \end{example}

    \begin{block}{My block}
        A block.
    \end{block}    

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]