# beamer.sty: modify block template

Tags: beamer, theorems

I would like to redefine a detail of the block templates for Beamer's theorem environment. The title should contain the additional text not in rounded brackets, but in another format. The fine manual says "this can be changed by the template", but I can't find this particular part of the template. I think it should be in `beamerbasetheorems.sty` ...

Comment: Here are many posts which do that such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347274/121799).

Comment: Yes & no. The post you linked offers only modifications of the colors. But how to change eg the brackets to braces or the like?

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding lines of code are to find in `beamerinnertheme.sty`

I modified it (for my requirements) to

```
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \hfill\itshape\inserttheoremaddition\fi%
  }%
}
```