# Modifiying environments color (theorem, definition, etc) in beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

I'm not used to modify LaTeX environments and it's my first time with beamer style, so I'm having some style issues.

1. Justifying text.
2. Changing definition/theorem/lemma headers to spanish.
3. Changing colors of each of those enviroments.

First two I have them covered (or seems so). The third is the one I haven't fixed yet. I guess that it's not that hard, but I've barely done any command editions, so I'm not sure about how to make it.

For example. If I code

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish]{beamer} 

\usepackage{ragged2e} % Seems to allow /justify command.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Seems to be essential for syllable breaking.
                            % Despite special characters like 'ñ' didn't require it.


%TEMA Y COLOR
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{default}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Example frame.}
      \begin{lemma}
        Una función $f \colon \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ presenta en $x^{*}$ un máximo global si, y sólo si, $-f$ presenta en $x^{*}$ un mínimo global.
    \end{lemma}
    
    \begin{proof}
        $x^{*} \text{ es máximo global de } f \text{ en } \Omega \Longleftrightarrow$
        
        $\Longleftrightarrow f(x^{*}) \geq f(x), \ \forall x \in \Omega \Longleftrightarrow$
        
        $\Longleftrightarrow -f(x^{*}) \leq -f(x), \ \forall x \in \Omega \Longleftrightarrow$
        
        $\Longleftrightarrow x^{*} \text{ es mínimo global de } -f \text{ en } \Omega$
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I get the output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\setbeamercolor`.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{default}

% Additional code
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=green!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=green!10}
% Additional code



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example frame.}
    \begin{lemma}
        Una función $f \colon \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ presenta en $x^{*}$ un máximo global si, y sólo si, $-f$ presenta en $x^{*}$ un mínimo global.
    \end{lemma}
    
    \begin{proof}
        $x^{*} \text{ es máximo global de } f \text{ en } \Omega \Longleftrightarrow$
        
        $\Longleftrightarrow f(x^{*}) \geq f(x), \ \forall x \in \Omega \Longleftrightarrow$
        
        $\Longleftrightarrow -f(x^{*}) \leq -f(x), \ \forall x \in \Omega \Longleftrightarrow$
        
        $\Longleftrightarrow x^{*} \text{ es mínimo global de } -f \text{ en } \Omega$
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

`fg` and `bg` stand for foreground and background colors respectively. See the section named "Colors" in beamer's user guide for more information.

[image]

### Edit

If you need different colors for lemma and proof blocks, refer to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347274/133968.